# Which users/groups should be migrated to LDAP?

Tags: debian, authentication, openldap

On a modern Debian distro, we're migrating towards centralized authentication using OpenLDAP - rather than using the normal Unix authentication (`pam_unix(8)`, `/etc/passwd`). The reason for this is to have synchronized logins on several Linux desktops / Samba servers.

There are plenty of guides on how to do this - [answers on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30588971/how-to-migrate-local-os-users-and-groups-to-ldap-debian-wheezy), the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/MigrationTools) and the [Gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Centralized_authentication_using_OpenLDAP).

Some guides say there are users/groups that you shouldn't migrate - such as daemons, root.

Can someone explain which users/groups you shouldn't migrate, and why?

Comment: Think about what users are needed prior to the network starting and connection to LDAP infra being established.  And think about what processes/services you'd want to continue running in the event of LDAP infra failure.

Comment: Thanks, so presumably for the use case I mentioned, you would normally expect that people's logins would be on LDAP, but all daemons using /etc/passwd? And presumably you wouldn't want to migrate root in case the LDAP server was down?

Comment: Yes, just moving "personal, non-system accounts" to LDAP is a common approach.

Comment: Are there any examples of daemons / system accounts which might be migrated?

Comment: Basically every user account that has a uid below 1000 is a system account. With most of them you can't even login, neither they have a password. If you plan to do LDAP authentication, only uids >=1000 should be considered. I recommend to migrate not a single  system/daemon account.

Comment: If steve or chaos can summarise the responses in an answer then I will accept it. In summary, normally only user accounts are migrated. The reasons for this : i) Not wanting to rely on the network link being available ii) Having to wait for the network service/LDAP to start iii) Daemons don't have password - all these rule out both daemons and the root account.

Comment: You probably also don't want an account for a daemon which is not even installed.